# Dynamically split an array into subarrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
const giftcards = [
  {
    fromuserid: 1,
    amount: 10,
    date: new Date(),
    touserid: 11,
  },
  {
    fromuserid: 1,
    amount: 20,
    date: new Date(),
    touserid: 11,

  },
  {
    fromuserid: 2,
    amount: 10,
    date: new Date(),
    touserid: 11,
  },
  {
    fromuserid: 2,
    amount: 10,
    date: new Date(),
    touserid: 11,

  },
  {
    fromuserid: 3,
    amount: 10,
    date: new Date(),
    touserid: 11,

  }
]
```

I achieved this, which is shown in the useEffect hook:

```js
const giftcards = [
  {
    fromuserid: 1,
    amounts: [{
        amount: 10,
        date: new Date(),
        touserid: 11,
      },
      {
        amount: 20,
        date: new Date(),
        touserid: 11,
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    fromuserid: 2,
    amounts: [{
        amount: 10,
        date: new Date(),
        touserid: 11,

      },
      {
        amount: 10,
        date: new Date(),
        touserid: 11,

      }
    ]
  },
  {
    fromuserid: 3,
    amounts: [{
      amount: 10,
      date: new Date(),
      touserid: 11,

    }]
  }
]
```

The solution that was given works except that i would like to make it dynamic.

Meaning, in my app, I allow the user to arrange how the array will be sorted.

For example,

```js
const [sort, setSort] = useState('fromuserid')
   const [results, setResults] = useState([])
   <div>
     <select value={sort} onChange={(e)=> setSort(e.target.value)}>
      <option value='fromuserid'>Sort by Buyer</option>
       <option value='touserid'>Sort by Receiver</option>
       <option value='date'>Sort by Date</option>
     </select>
   </div>
```

then in the:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  allgiftcards.forEach(({
    fromuserid,
    date,
    from,
    giftcardid,
    message,
    template,
    touserid,
    amount,
    paid
  }) => {
    map.has(fromuserid) || map.set(fromuserid, {
      fromuserid,
      cards: []
    })
    map.get(fromuserid).cards.push({
      date,
      from,
      giftcardid,
      message,
      template,
      touserid,
      amount,
      paid
    })
  })
  setResults([...map.values()])
}, [sort])
```

Here is what i mean by dynamic. If the user selected date, I would like for it to look something like:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  allgiftcards.forEach(({
    fromuserid,
    date,
    from,
    giftcardid,
    message,
    template,
    touserid,
    amount,
    paid
  }) => {
    map.has(date) || map.set(date, {
      date,
      cards: []
    })
    map.get(date).cards.push({
      date,
      from,
      giftcardid,
      message,
      template,
      touserid,
      amount,
      paid
    })
  })
  setResults([...map.values()])
}, [sort])
```

But It seems to me that having a bunch of if and else statements would be bad coding and would create a lot of extra code, so looking for a nice and clean solution

Comment: I actually think you made your life much more complicated putting your data in that new format. It would have been a lot simpler to filter and sort on properties like date or `touserid` in the original set, and _then_ create some new data based on that new sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really isn't a question of React (or where-ever `useEffect` comes from).  This is really a general Javascript question, and it's a problem that suits itself well for solving with functional programming, or at least, with one of the staples of functional programming: `reduce`

In this case, you could supply the 2nd argument which is the initial value of the accumulator -- in this example an empty object works well.  You can choose any key from the data to bucket the results:

```
// Choose a key that each object in the set has, e.g. 'fromuserid' or 'touserid'
const group_by = 'fromuserid';

let bucketed = giftcards.reduce(function (acc, x) {
    let pivot = x[group_by]
    let current_vals = (acc.hasOwnProperty(pivot) ? acc[pivot] : []);
    current_vals.push(x);
    acc[pivot] = current_vals;
    return acc
}, {});

console.log(bucketed);
```

If you really needed to land on the second data structure you shared, you could jostle your initialValue and the exact placement of values into the accumulator, but hopefully this demonstrate the concept of how to dynamically choose how to group the data.

Comment: How would you go about doing it if it were to be sorted by date  it was purchased (1 day frame)

Comment: Remember: as developers we don't solve complex problems. We divide things up into simple problems, and then solve those.  So the first step would be to add a new stubbed date field, e.g. one holding only `YYYY-MM-DD`, and then group by that field.  You could do this using JS's `map` function to prep the data for the `reduce` example in the post.

Comment: I see that the format is in an object like this: {id: Array(n), ...}, how do I access the id?

Comment: WOuld it be possible to transform the bukcted in an array format?

Answer (score 1):

[This codepen](https://codepen.io/commonzen/pen/NWpZPQz) shows how to dynamically bucket an array of objects based on a specific property. Below is a sample of the callback function you can pass to the reducer -- included in the [example](https://codepen.io/commonzen/pen/NWpZPQz).

```
function groupBy(accum, current, groupKey){
  const val = current[groupKey]
  const {[groupKey]:_, ...content} = current
  if (val in accum){
    accum[val].push(content)
  }
  else accum[val] = [content]
  return accum
}
```

Comment: In my case, I'm using a firebase timestamp as the date, how would i convert the date before its value is given